# How make report or query in Team Foundation Server

Tags: tfs

That shows all work items having more completed hours than original estimate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using TFS 2010 then this is easy.  If you are using TFS 2008 or older then you will have to make a report (and that is out of my expertise).

For TFS 2010 you can make a new query and use the `< [Field]` operator.  That will allow you to put a field on both sides of the operation.

I mocked up a query that you could import if you like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WorkItemQuery Version="1">
  <TeamFoundationServer>
  http://YourTFS2010Server:8080/tfs/YourCollection</TeamFoundationServer>
  <TeamProject>ProjectName</TeamProject>
  <Wiql>
  SELECT  [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], 
          [System.AssignedTo], [System.State] 
  FROM    WorkItems 
  WHERE   [System.TeamProject] = @project 
          AND [Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.OriginalEstimate] &lt;
              [Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.CompletedHours] 
  ORDER BY [System.Id]
  </Wiql>
</WorkItemQuery>
```

You would need to sub in your values for your server and then save it off as a `.wiq` file.  (Also I don't know the real names of your fields.  I just made a stab with what you were asking for in your question)

After you save it off as a `.wiq`, you can then open the file in visual studio and run it.

Comment: Super - missed that "Field" setting completely